# $.ajax throwing parse error on valid JSON

Tags: javascript, json, jquery

I have run into a small problem. I am trying to get access to a JSON file using a jQuery `$.ajax` call I double checked online and my JSON code is valid. When I make the call it throws a parse error with Syntax Error in the JSON.

You can find the error by visiting http://michael-nolan.com/

Here is my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $.ajax(
        { type: "GET",
          url: 'projects/projects.json', 
          dataType: "json", 
        success: function(results)
        { 
            console.log("Success!"); 
        }, 
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
        { 
            console.log(textStatus); console.log(errorThrown); 
        } 
    });
});
```

and here is my JSON

```
{
    "projects":
    [
        {
            "title":"Adobe Suite",
            "description":"Some stuff",
            "imgsrc":"img/adobe_suite_description.png"
        },
        {
            "title":"Gridlock",
            "description":"Stuff",
            "imgsrc":"img/gridlock_description.png"
        },
        {
            "title":"Open Cart",
            "description":"more stuff",
            "imgsrc":"img/opencart_description.png"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Have you used Fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to make sure the server is sending what you expect?

Comment: can you show the error? Also like tmack said try it it http://jsfiddle.net/ so that you can replicated it and we can see it. http://jsfiddle.net/vqagE/ parsed fine for me. Wow sorry tmack, completely different. I will have to check that out myself.

Comment: @John I updated my question with a link to the website that the problem is happening on.

Comment: i have tried it and working as expected...

Comment: Says *"Unexpected token"*, looking for it now

Comment: Also, the JSON in your question above is **not** what is actually coming through in the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error has something to do with the whitespace (probably the newline character) between the two paragraphs in your second array entry

```
...in the game.</p>
    <p>Gridlock...
^
|
the problem
```

Comment: See my answer for the solution. Just replace the tab with `\t` and newline with `\n`

Answer (score 2):

Works fine in Chrome, IE is particularly strict with JSON (of all things).

Look out for the newline in your 2nd and 3rd descriptions. I suspect that's what's failing in IE.

Comment: This was definitely causing the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code and its working for me and i also tried it on your site and gave `304 not modified`.

So try using `getJson()` jQuery method.

```
$.getJSON('projects/projects.json', function(data) {

});
```

Comment: When I use `$.getJSON()` It doesn't look like it runs the callback. When I look at fiddler It is still throwing a 304

Answer (score 0):

Your code worked fine when I tested it.  Depending on what the Syntax error is, I might check to see how the json is being generated and if navigating to projects/projects.json produces the json correctly.  If the json is generated, try replacing it with static json and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

There are tabs and newlines in your JSON, which causes the parser to fail. Replace each tab instance with `\t` and newline with `\n` For example:

**Example JSON File:**

```
{
    textWithTabs : "This is text with \t a tab and \n newline"
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var o = JSON.parse(json);

console.log(o.textWithTabs); //This is text with     a tab and ↵ newline
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to try this:

```
{
"projects": [
    {
        "title": "Adobe Suite",
        "description": "<p>With years of experience using the Adobe Suite products I have skills that range from creating vector artwork in Adobe Illustrator, arranging web layouts in Adobe Photoshop, and creating print layouts in Adobe InDesign</p>",
        "imgsrc": "img/adobe_suite_description.png"
    },
    {
        "title": "Gridlock",
        "description": "<p>In my Sophomore year in college I worked with Jayson Fitch as an artist on a isometric 2d shooter called Gridlock. We as a team created all of the art assets that are being used in the game.</p><p> Gridlock is still in development and we hope to release it on the OUYA.Check out it's development blog here. <a href='http://gridlock-game.tumblr.com'>www.Gridlock-Game.Tumblr.com</a></p>",
        "imgsrc": "img/gridlock_description.png"
    },
    {
        "title": "Open Cart",
        "description": "<p>As a freelance project I initiated an overhaul of the Legendary Realms Terrain e-commerce storefront. This entailed a complete visual re-branding as well as creating a backend solution to expand online payment options.</p><p> Feel free to check them out at < a href = 'lrterrain.com' > Legendary Realms Terrain < /a></p > ",
        "imgsrc": "img/opencart_description.png"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The error being logged sounds like its a problem with your json. Try switching the `[ ]`  for a `{}` in your json.

Comment: The problem is that projects is supposed to be an array. Also, setting it to `{}` would invalidate the JSON file.